# Rename the [google-reflections] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, moderation

The library has nothing to do with Google in the first place, except of hosting on google-code. Now even this fragile connection is gone, the library is hosted on GitHub and Bintray.

The name [reflections] is a bit ambiguous, so maybe [reflections-util]?

Comment: There are 29 questions currently tagged with that.

Comment: @rene I am pretty newbie in the meta so I am not sure what that means. Is it bad? Or good? Reason to retag or not to retag?

Comment: Well, I would not think in good or bad more in extra information that helps to decide what to do. I'm not into java at all so I'm not much of help here. Is that library going to be used a lot? Can you find some question that now don't have that tag?

Comment: I do support to get rid of the google- part. Not sure though what its final name should be. Looks like most java people just talk about reflections so I think that should be the one....

Comment: I'm the creator of that package. This tag was created by the stackoverflow comunity, and is the de-facto name used by the community for the Reflections.